# What's the easiest way to allow users to create their own forms on my web app?

Tags: asp.net

My ASP.NET web app needs to support the ability for users to create their own forms, complete with textboxes, dropdowns, radio buttons with some logic (required field, etc.).  Is there some third party tool that's already geared towards this?

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) has this functionality, you would, however, have to make your site a DNN site to utilize it directly.

Their system is fairly well suited to the scenario you describe, though, since you build pages by placing existing modules (think User Controls) on specific areas of the page (center, left, right) and then can re-arrange them within the areas.  Certainly worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well it would integrate with your system (if at all), but take a look at http://www.formassembly.com/ - it might give you an idea of what is involved, should you need to make one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not appropriate for what you're looking to do, but just in case you might want to check out [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/)

It's an online form builder service but it's a hosted application rather than a library, so may not be suitable for your purposes. On the off chance it is helpful though I figured I'd post it since it generates some really nice forms.